# Apache Cassandra VS Spark VS Hive VS Storm

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cassandra, hive, apache-storm

I understand individually what each is but i am having a hard time wrapping my head around on the differences in use cases.

Could one describe briefly what each is and a use case example of when one could be choosen over the others.

My understanding was that Spark and Cassandra are not even comparable, but my coworker argued that they were the same species.

As a newbie in big data, I do apologize in advance if this is a strictly opinion/preferred basis. Please do let me know if so and i will take the question down.

Comment: Spark is not a database. Your coworker doesn't know what they're talking about

Comment: I concur with @cricket_007 **Spark is definitely not a DB.** Ppl who says that usually know nothing about Spark with all due respect ofc !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of those listed, Cassandra is the only database. Hive is a SQL execution engine over Hadoop. SparkSQL offers the same query language, but Spark is more adaptable to other use cases like streaming and machine learning. Storm is a real time, stream processing framework ; Spark does micro batches, Storm immediately processes messages. (As an aside, I feel like Storm is an old framework. I've been told Flink is nicer to work with than Storm. Heron is aiming to be the next generation of Storm.)

Spark works best on systems with lots of memory. Hive can arguably process more raw data in bulk than Spark or Cassandra by using SQL optimization like partition pruning, predicate pushdown, and operating on columnar formats of ORC or Parquet.

Spark works with Cassandra as equally as Hive, however, more real-time use cases will want to use Cassandra as Hive queries must start MapReduce/Tez executions, which cost several seconds, compared to milliseconds with the correct Cassandra data model.

Cassandra is very data model focused... There is no reason you cannot dump data into Hadoop/Hive, then export to a Cassandra model. Or, you could use Hbase instead of Cassandra and have a similar model, with the tradeoff of Availability (see CAP theorem).

If you're interested in Spark and Cassandra use cases, the SMACK stack is one of the popular installation setups.

Comment: that certainly clears things up a bit. So are you saying that basically you cant really have Spark on its own (logically)? theres got to be either Cassandra, Hive, Hbase, etc.. in addition of spark, to actually store the data? So spark would be compute only, while cassandra is compute + storage? Am i understanding it correctly?

Comment: Spark is for compute, yes. You need to pair it with some storage layer for persisting results. HDFS and S3 are common file systems. Hive and Cassandra are common structured storage systems that support SQL-like queries from external systems for other processing

Comment: Even thought this question is broad and should be closed, I upvoted your answer because you said that **Spark isn't a database**.

Answer (score -2):

Storm is indeed a old framework. Just to highlight a few things about Heron. (Full disclosure, I am one of the co-creators of Heron). Heron has gone beyond Storm in several ways -

Heron introduced a lot of new ideas such as back pressure, notion of modularity similar to microkernels (for constantly changing big data landscape), isolation, native containerization, process based instead of thread based for troubleshooting, etc.

While Heron started with Storm API due to the need for backward compatibility at Twitter (which open sourced Storm), several new APIs has been added. Streamlets are the new functional API that have been introduced - that translates into operators for physical execution.

Low level api similar to Storm API have been added for Python. Streamlet functional API is available in Python as well. The key advantage is Python API based topologies run in native python interpreter and directly receive data - unlike Storm that use multi-language protocol based on stdin/stdout which forks several additional process and very slow.

Support for YAML based topology support is already available. Additional native support for languages like C++, Scala and Go are upcoming.

Heron can support diverse workloads in a single deployment - latency sensitive vs throughput sensitive with simple configuration change at each topology.

Heron ships with optional storage layer called Apache BookKeeper which provides distributed replicated log. This provides a seamless experience for distributing job jars and also provides a stateful storage for exactly once processing.

Heron can natively support several scheduler deployments such as Kubernetes, DC/OS, Nomad and standalone thereby taking advantage of those scheduler features.

Heron pioneered the work of self regulating systems based on the operational experiences it went through - auto scaling and self healing of topologies.

Furthermore, it has been in production at significant scale for more than 3 years at multiple companies.